# Not able to add css file in thymeleaf

Tags: css, thymeleaf

I am new in thymeleaf and trying to add .css file in thymeleaf but not able to load the css file.
 My css file is in src/main/resources/templates/style.css

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

 <head>
 <title>State 1 for Document</title>
 </head>

 <div th:if="${InstaPanState==1 and InstaPanStateStatus==0}">
 <head lang="en">
    <title>Instaveritas PAN Verification</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' 
   href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' 
    th:href="@{https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
    family=Open+Sans:400,300}"/>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' 
     href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' 
     th:href="@{https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
     family=Open+Sans:400,300}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"  
    th:href="@{/style.css}" media="all"/>
</head>
```

Comment: You'll want to post your config and describe exactly what's not working - do you get any exceptions or does the CSS just not appear on your page?  Do a View Source on the generated HTML and post that too.

Comment: just css not appear

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a resource mapping, see http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder under resources called static and a subfolder called css and move your css files there, something like: `resources/static/css/style.css`

Then call it like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/>
```